# Eclipse Debugging: Customized Breaktpoints Groups?

Tags: eclipse, debugging, breakpoints

Hi and thank you for reading.

I use Eclipse Debugging mode to understand some components of a massive Framework. Now I have something like Workflow A and Workflow B. I have set breakpoints in workflow A and understood how it work. Then I have set breakpoints in workflow B, but would like the breakpoints in workflow A to be there but not be called, so I can use them again at a later point.

What I would like to have is a way to enable all breakpoints in workflow A or workflow B without removing the breakpoints. Is there a way to do that?

Thanks,

evgeni

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Breakpoint view menu (click the inverted triangle icon on the top right), look under the 'Group by' entry. You can use either breakpoint 'workingsets' and have a custom grouping or group by projects or files. Once you have a grouping enabling/disabling everything in a group becomes trivial.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this is not the type of grouping I would like to have. E.g. I might have a two breakpoints in one class, the one is for my workflow A, the other for the workflow B. There is not possibility to put this into two separate groups, if I see it right.

Comment: In this case you have to use breakpoint workingsets to have a custom grouping.

Comment: oh, right, got it. there are working sets for breakpoints. I assumed it would be the working sets for the projects. Thanks